# Double meaning of relief

Tags: meaning, pronunciation, french, homonyms

I was writing a report for an assignment and found myself wanting to write the following sentence.

> The resulting landscape shows more *relief*.

In Dutch, "relief" only has the French meaning (cf. *le relief*) related to geography so it came natural to me. Then I realized that "relief" in English also (and probably mostly) refers to the feeling. I double checked if it could even be used with the French meaning and found this: https://www.thoughtco.com/relief-geography-definition-1434845.

My question is whether the sentence above makes sense or is there an other word I should use instead to describe the "non-flatness" of the landscape?

Additionaly, is the word pronounced differently when using it with its meaning in French?

Comment: When you say "landscape" are you referring to the actual, physical, landscape or a picture or other representation of the physical landscape.

Comment: The assignment is for a mathematics course. The sentence is referring to a probablity landscape which in this specific case is a 3D surface. In one case, the surface is very flat, but when some parameters are changed it becomes more 'not flat'.

Comment: Very common https://www.google.com/search?q=relief+maps

Comment: I would say "greater relief", "higher relief" or "sharper relief" rather than "more relief". I'm not sure why though... "more relief" just seems ever so slightly off

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You’ve already made the right choice, because *relief* is the precise and correct word for what you want. It is pronounced the same way that its homograph is, the one you mentioned being about feelings and such.

The OED lists these two words completely separately. In fact, it has three different nouns here, although the first is obsolete as of the 16th century or so. These words came into all the European languages around the same time, because the literate were frequently literate in many languages and freely borrowed from one another.

1. † *noun*¹: *c.* 1225–1589 
   Several related meanings connected to scraps left-overs, mostly those  from a meal. No longer current. Their etymological notes mention:

   > Compare Old Occitan *releu*, Catalan *relleu* (13th cent. as †*releu*;
   > now regional), Spanish *relieve* (1251; chiefly in plural *relieves*; now
   > archaic), Italian *rilievo* (a1288; now archaic or literary; also as
   > †*rilevo*, †*relievo*), all originally and chiefly in sense 2,
   > and Middle Dutch *relief, relif* remainder, (specifically) remains of food
   > left after a meal (both late 13th cent.).  Although in early use the
   > English word often translates classical Latin *reliquiae* (plural) (see
   > **reliquiae** *n.*), neither **relief** *n*.¹ nor its French etymon are
   > etymologically related to the Latin plural noun.
2. *noun*²: *a.* 1325–present
   This is the more common of the two current meanings.  The OED places it in the same frequency band as it places *dog, horse, ship, machine, mile, assessment, army, career*, which means that it occurs between 10 and 100 times per million words in typical modern English usage.  They identify its etymons as (Old) French *releef*, *relief*; the verb *relieve*, and Latin *relevium.* Specifically they mention:

   > Probably partly < Anglo-Norman *releef, relef, releff, relif,* Anglo-Norman
   > and Middle French *relief* (French (now hist.) *relief*) payment made to
   > the overlord by the heir of a feudal tenant on taking up possession of the
   > vacant estate (1215 or earlier in Anglo-Norman), formal acknowledgement of
   > feudal tenure made by a vassal to a lord (13th cent. in Old French),
   > *alleviation* (late 14th cent. or earlier in Anglo-Norman; < *relever*
   > relieve v.), and partly (especially in later use) < *relieve* v. In sense
   > 1a perhaps also partly < post-classical Latin relevium relevy n.1; compare
   > Middle Dutch *relief, relif*, in same sense (end of the 13th cent.; < Old
   > French; Dutch (now hist.) *relief*), and also post-classical Latin
   > *relevamentum* (see **relievement** n.), *relevatio* (see **relevation** n.).
3. *noun*³: 1606–present
   This is pronounced the same way as the previous one is, rhyming with *belief*. The OED places it in their frequency band 5, unlike the previous word which they place in 6. That means it occurs from 1 to 10 times per million words in ordinary English. They mention:

   > The shift away from the everyday language found in bands 8-6 is apparent in nouns (e.g. *surveillance, assimilation, tumult, penchant, paraphrase, admixture*)

   So it isn't super rare in any way; those are normal words. They identify its etymons as Italian *rilievo, relevo, relievo* and French *relief,* and they suggest that one

   > Compare Spanish *relievo* (late 16th cent.; < Italian or French), Dutch
   > *reliëf* (1659 as *relief*; < French), early modern German *relievo* (c1650; <
   > Italian), German *Relief* (18th cent.; < French).

As I said, this is the right word to use here. Let me cherry-pick of few of the senses they cite it gets used in today, along with their most recent of many, many citations for each of these I’ve selected.

> 1. a. Moulding, carving, stamping, etc., in which the design stands out
>    from a plane surface so as to have a natural and solid appearance. Also:
>    work done in this way; the part which so projects.  Sometimes with
>    modifying word specifying the degree of projection: see *high relief* n. 1,
>    *low relief* n., *bas-relief* n.
>
>    - 2008   *Edmond* (Oklahoma) *Sun* (Nexis) 4 Oct.  
>       The heaviest object, a marble sarcophagus,..is heavily decorated with carved relief.
> 2. c. *figurative* and in figurative context. Vividness, distinctness, or
>    prominence due to contrast or method of presentation. Frequently as ***to
>    throw*** (or ***bring,*** etc.) ***into relief***.
>
>    - 1991   K. Jones *Learning not to be First* ix. 103 
>       Lizzie became pregnant, and the sickly young woman's fecundity threw Christina's own barrenness into stark relief.
> 3. b. *Physical Geography.* The manner or degree of variation in elevation
>    of a part of the surface of the earth (or other planetary body).
>
>    - 1990   *Technol. Rev*. Nov. 10/1 
>       Some scientists have said the sharp relief of many mountains suggests these areas have recently grown.

They list many compounds in which this version of *relief* is used, including: *in relief,
relief block,
relief carving,
relief construction,
relief decoration,
relief map,
relief panel,
relief plate,
relief polish,
relief polishing,
relief portion,
relief print,
relief printing,
relief process,
relief stamp,
relief stamper,*
and *relief tablet*. In my own personal experience, *relief map* is the one of those that I come across the most often.

So this is a perfectly normal word, and I would not hesitate to use it in your technical context.

Comment: +1 anecdotally we would always talk about "relief maps" and "relief lines" in geography lessons (in Britain). So while it's not a commonly used term outside of technical contexts (that is, you probably wouldn't say it in an everyday setting) I imagine it's probably more well-known than most technical terms because of its use in school-level geography.

Comment: +1. I'd also add there is no risk of ambiguity with the other meaning of *'relief'* (landscapes do not say "I'm so relieved"!)

Comment: There is also the military meaning in English, roughly "receiving assistance from friendly forces". For example "The Relief of Mafeking" in Victorian times which led  to old puns about "Mafeking being relieved" in the emotional sense. There is also "relief of suffering" by means of humanitarian actions. At one time what we now call 'unemployment benefit' and other similar payment was called "poor law relief".

Comment: @BoldBen I think those are part of the meaning of 2. *noun*²

Comment: The "relief" of a guitar neck seems to be where meanings intersect. It's a slight bow (a kind of shape profile) which makes the instrument more playable at the higher fret positions while sacrificing less, (relieving your fingers of effort).   :)

Comment: @BoldBen I was thinking of "a levy of troops". Never realized until now that levy ties in with this as is shown in that 2nd definition (from reLEVAation).

Answer (score 1):

Relief is OK if there's sufficient context, but for just a few more characters you could just write out what you mean:

...shows more variation in height.

...shows a larger range of elevations.

...shows more extreme values.

...shows a wider range of values.

...shows more contrast.

Etc. Mix and match to your liking, as pertains to whatever you're trying to show with your map.

Answer (score 0):

What about "the resulting landscape **looks rough**"?
Or "the result is **a rough landscape"**?

> - ["rough"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rough) - "marked by inequalities, ridges, or projections on the surface,  having a broken, uneven, or bumpy surface."

From the web:

I took a long walk north of the town, out into the pastures where **the land was so rough** that it had never been ploughed up.[**¹**](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/rough)

During several ice ages , glacial ice up to one mile thick covered the region , modifying the **rough landscape** created by the previous era's uplifting .[**²**](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=0F-HZCgEcooC&pg=PA194&dq=%22rough+landscape%22&hl=pt-BR&newbks=1&newbks_redir=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiSk8z_guHwAhXUlJUCHbqzBqcQ6AEwA3oECAUQAg)

We reached the summit after a hard climb , and had a grand view of the **rough landscape**.[**³**](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=3AmCAAAAMAAJ&q=%22rough+landscape%22&dq=%22rough+landscape%22&hl=pt-BR&newbks=1&newbks_redir=1&printsec=frontcover&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiSk8z_guHwAhXUlJUCHbqzBqcQ6AEwCXoECAYQAg)

postscript - You can always use **"uneven"** or **"slightly uneven"** (an uneven surface)

> - uneven -  "not even : not level or smooth" [**MW**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/uneven)

Comment: Hmm, that's not really what I mean because the surface is still really smooth. It's just wavy, or has more pronounced differences in altitude.